# Por que no puedo agegar mi nombre completo?

Tags: c++

Estoy creando un codigo con C++ que solicita los datos del usuario, al pedir el nombre si ingreso un solo nombre por ejemplo "Pedro" El programa continua formulando las demas preguntas, en cambio si escribo el nombre completo de la persona el programa automaticamente termina sin pedir los demas datos.

```
string name;  //Ingresar un dato de texto
int edad;    
char sexo[10];   //Almacenar un caracter o unidad de texto (una letra)
float estatura;

cout<<"\nBienvenido al registro de datos, por favor ingresa lo que se pide.";

cout<<"\nIngresa tu nombre: ";
cin>>name;

cout<<"\nCual es tu estatura: ";
cin>>estatura;

cout<<"\nTu nombre es: "<<name;

cout<<"\nAhora ingresa tu edad: ";
cin>>edad;

cout<<"\nCual es tu sexo?: ";
cin>>sexo;

cout<<"\nTu nombre es: "<<name<< "\nMides: "<<estatura<<"m" <<"\nTu edad es: " <<edad<<"\nEres: " <<sexo;





return 0;
```

}

Comment: `cin>>` lee hasta que encuentra un separador, que podria ser un espacio, un tab, una linea nueva, etc. Si quieres leer textos con espacios tendras que usar `std::getline`.

Answer (score 1):

Eso es porque al detectar un espacio, la forma con la que estás intentando obtener la cadena, deja de obtener valores.
Para solucionar esto puedes emplear la función `getline`, de este modo podrás obtener la cadena con los espacios.

El código te quedaría algo así:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define num_char_name 50

int main() {

    char name[num_char_name];  //Ingresar un dato de texto
    int edad;    
    char sexo[10];   //Almacenar un caracter o unidad de texto (una letra)
    float estatura;

    cout<<"\nBienvenido al registro de datos, por favor ingresa lo que se pide.";

    cout<<"\nIngresa tu nombre: ";
    cin.getline(name, num_char_name, '\n');

    cout<<"\nCual es tu estatura: ";
    cin>>estatura;

    cout<<"\nAhora ingresa tu edad: ";
    cin>>edad;

    cout<<"\nCual es tu sexo?: ";
    cin>>sexo;

    cout<<"\nTu nombre es: "<<name<< "\nMides: "<<estatura<<"m" <<"\nTu edad es: " <<edad<<"\nEres: " <<sexo;

    return 0;
}
```

Un saludo.

Comment: En lugar de usar un array de caractres y usar `#define` para las constantes (Que
es mas C que C++), tendrias que usar `std::string` (Ademas de que es lo que ya
esta usando el OP en la pregunta).